# FullCalendar : How to have event opening in new tab/window calendar view?

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Sorry to ask this simple question but I've looked everywhere in this forum and in Google and can't find a simple, direct answer for this.
I'm using the FooEvents plugin that relies on the FullCalendar library. In the calendar view, I'm desperately trying to have a new window/tab opening when clicking on the events.

I'm pretty new to JS so I don't even know in which file the code should be modified. function.php of fullcalendar.js ? Also, I feel it has to do with a similar code :

```
eventClick: function(event) { 
  if(event.title) { 
    window.open(getUrl(event.title),'_blank'); 
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your precious help.

Comment: so, to clarify, window.open() isn't working for you, somehow? What happens when you use that code? Do you get an error, or some other unexpected behaviour? What does your "getUrl()" function do, exactly?

Comment: P.S. It's worth clarifying...which version of fullCalendar are you using? I'm not familiar with this "FooEvents" plugin, nor what version of fullCalendar it relies on. I mention this because, the code above looks like it's designed for version 3 (because of `event.title`) whereas the latest version is version 4, where the signature of this callback has changed and to get the title you'd need `eventClick: function(info) { 
  if(info.event.title) ...etc`.

Comment: Thank for answering ! The fullCalendar version FooEvents is currently using is apparently v.3.10, but I can update it to 4 if needed.
My main problem is a JS newbie one - I'm not sure the code above works because I'm not sure I've added it the right way, in the right file ! Where should this be included ?
Thank you so much.

Comment: it should be within the options when you declare the fullCalendar e.g. I imagine that somewhere you've got some code along the lines of `$("#calendar").fullCalendar({ ....etc` containing some options for setting up the calendar. It should be added as one of those options. There are some examples in the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventClick

Comment: well I do have the fullcalendar.js, shouldn't it be directly included in this file ?

Comment: No, that's just the internal program logic of fullCalendar. Somewhere else in your JavaScript code would be the place where you call upon that code to actually create a calendar in the page, and specify how you want it to behave. Or maybe that code is auto-generated by your fooEvents plugin...in which case they hopefully have a separate API where you can hook into the underlying fullCalendar functionality. Depends if they provided such a thing or not.

Comment: https://www.fooevents.com/documentation/getting-started-fooevents-calendar/ is the only reference I can find to it in the public documentation.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer ! I dug a little... and this is where the fullcalendar is called : 

<div id='<?php echo $calendar_id; ?>' class="fooevents_calendar" style="clear:both"></div>
<script>
(function($) {

    var localObj = '<?php echo $localArgs['json_events']; ?>';
    var settings = JSON.parse(localObj);    
    
    if( $('#'+settings.id).length ) {
        
        jQuery('#'+settings.id).fullCalendar(settings);
        
    } 

})(jQuery);
</script>

So is this where I should add the above code ? Sorry again about being a JS newbie...

Comment: yes more or less. In this case you will need to add it to the settings object before that gets passed to the calendar. So something like `var settings = JSON.parse(localObj); settings.eventClick = function(event) { 
  if(event.title) { 
    window.open(getUrl(event.title),'_blank'); 
  }; if( $('#'+settings.id).length ) { jQuery('#'+settings.id).fullCalendar(settings); }` Of course, you will also need to define a function called "getUrl" which can read your event's title and make a suitable URL from it, if you haven't already got such a thing.

Comment: Yes I guess something is missing because it is not working yet :/ I don't want to overindulge because you've been really nice already helping me. But I'm really new to JS : what sort of getUrl function has to be defined and where ? 
Thank you so much !

Comment: It can be defined anywhere in your code _above_ where the eventRender function is defined. As for how it should work, I don't know...where did you get that example above from? Does it show such a function as part of the tutorial? What do you think the function should do? I have no idea how you are proposing to use the event's title to generate a valid URL. I don't know what the URL you want looks like, whether it contains the title (or if the correct URL can even be derived from the title) or what. In theory you could write almost anything. Depends on how your application and data work.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using v5, you can achieve this with the snippet below.

```
eventClick: function(event) {
    if (event.event.url) {
      event.jsEvent.preventDefault();
      window.open(event.event.url, "_blank");
    }
}
```

More info about *eventClick* is [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick).

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.eo-fullcalendar').on( 'click', '.fc-event', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open( jQuery(this).attr('href'), '_blank' );
});
```